# Jquery multiple coundown

Tags: php, jquery, countdown

I found this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('tr[id]').each(function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     var count = parseInt($this.attr("id"));
     countdown = setInterval(function(){
         $('.remain', $this).html(count + " seconds remaining!");
         if (count-- == 0) {
           //do something
           clearInterval(countdown);
         }
     }, 1000);
  });  
});
```

and on the HTML this code:

```
<table>  
  <tr id="4236377487">
    <td class="remain"></td>
    <td>Something</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="768769080">
    <td class="remain"></td>
    <td>Something else</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The result is something like this:

```
4236375205 seconds remaining!   Something
768766798 seconds remaining!    Something else
```

I have a date in the following format 2011-10-29 10:05:00, I show this date by using `<?php echo $date ?>`

What i need is to pass the $date to the `<tr id=` so the time left to that date is shown but keeping the same format Y-m-d H:i:s or  even H:i:s will be great.

I just finish to check the jQuery Countdown plugin at http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html, but it doesn't suit me since I need multiple countdowns.

I hope this is clear and you can understand my question.
Thanks in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $('tr[id]').each(function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     var count = parseInt($this.attr("id"));
     countdown = setInterval(function(){
         var curDate = (new Date()).getMilliseconds();
         var newDate = new Date(count-curDate);
         var dateString = newDate.getHours() + ":" + newDate.getMinutes() + ":" + newDate.getSeconds();
         $('.remain', $this).html(dateString + " seconds remaining!");
         if (count-- == 0) {
           //do something
           clearInterval(countdown);
         }
     }, 1000);
  });  
});
```