# Multiple Jquery Countdowns inside html table

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-countdown

I am working on a project where I need to show the status of several auctions on one page. Each item has a different end date. I am using `cfquery` to pull the data from the database and then using `cfoutput` build a table. That part is fine. No problems there. My question is, How can I place multiple instances of [Keith Wood's countdown timer](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) in the table so each item has a countdown going?

This is my header for the table:

```
<table id="large" class="tablesorter" border="0" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="0" width="50%">
<thead>
<tr class="tablesorter-headerRow">
    <th id="itemnum"  class="sorter-numeric">ItemNum</th>
    <th id="highbidder"  class="sorter-numeric">HighBidder</th>
    <th id="closenum"  class="sorter-numeric">Time Left</th>
    <th id="highbidprice"  class="sorter-numeric">HighBid</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<cfoutput>
<!--- Code builds the table body --->
<div class="countdown-styled clearfix" style="width:200px;"></div>
</cfoutput>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have looked at these: 1) [Jquery multiple coundown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968041/jquery-multiple-coundown) 2) [multiple countdowns on same page with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883313/multiple-countdowns-on-same-page-with-jquery) but these either seem to include a unique row ID for each page then some other jquery code or just hard code the id. The problem with this is that I don't know how many items will be on the final version. Right now I have 35 but that isn't constant so I can't do that. Any ideas or help here? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: What does the table body output look like? How it is structured will directly affect the jQuery you use to trigger your countdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example from his site:

```
$(selector).countdown({until: new Date(2010, 12-1, 25)});
```

I assume you are doing something like this:

```
$('.countdown-styled').countdown({until: someDate});
```

So the idea is that each `$('.countdown-styled')` has a different date, and you just need to figure out how to specify the date for each different element.

```
$('.countdown-styled').each(function (idx) {
    var date = $(this).closest('tr').find('.date-label').text();

    $(this).countdown({ until: new Date(date) });
});
```

Of course, I don't know where to get the date from, since I can't see all your code, and you may need to tweak the code that makes a javascript Date object from the display, but that should get you started.